# Comparing tables and inserting values based on a condition (different structure)

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have two tables, one called "members" and another called "email_digest". They have different structures. I would like to have a query that:

1. Compares both tables
2. If a member from "members" is not in "email_digest", the query fetches the member ID from "members", adds it to "email_digest" and sets a value to its "frequency" column

How could I do that?

**Example:**

- TABLE members HAS COLUMNS member_id AND name
- DATA IN IT: 10 (member_id) AND John (name)
- TABLE email_digest HAS COLUMNS member_id AND frequency
- DATA IN IT: EMPTY
- Since "John" from members is not in email_digest, the query would add his member_id and the value "weekly" into frequency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can use `NOT EXISTS` to check if the value does not exist in your `email_digest` and then use it to insert data into your `email_digest` table.

Though I am not sure why `weekly` is the only chosen frequency,
you can use following query:

```
INSERT INTO email_digest(member_id, `frequency`)
SELECT m.`member_id`,'WEEKLY' FROM members m WHERE NOT EXISTS (
SELECT * FROM `email_digest` e WHERE e.`member_id`=m.`member_id`
)
```

Here is a sample:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `email_digest`;

CREATE TABLE `email_digest` (
  `member_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `frequency` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

/*Data for the table `email_digest` */


/*Table structure for table `members` */

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `members`;

CREATE TABLE `members` (
  `member_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

/*Data for the table `members` */

insert  into `members`(`member_id`,`name`) values (10,'John'),(9,'Asgar');
```

After using the query above, it will insert the data you need.

Comment: Hey @Asgar, thanks for helping! I'm getting a syntax error near "'FROM members m WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `email_digest' at line 2" (1064 error). "Weekly" is the default email frequency I want to use. I don't know if I let it clear, but It's not a value from the "members" table - it's from "email_digest".

Comment: I just removed the ` and it worked! Thank you so much!!! =)